# Scale Img Proportionally to Fill Entire Container without CSS Cover (javascript/React)

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

The image needs to fill both the entire width and height of the container but stay centered and proportional to its original size. I would like for it to be dynamic so the image will fill any screen size.

Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-fog-u7dud?file=/src/App.js:0-685

Please help!

```js
import "./styles.css";
import bgImage from "./bg.jpg";

const appContainerStyle = {
  height: "100vh",
  width: "100vw"
};
const imageContainerStyle = {
  height: "50%",
  width: "100%",
  backgroundColor: "red",
  display: "flex",
  justifyContent: "center",
  alignItems: "center"
};
const bgImageStyle = {
  height: "100%",
  width: "100%",
  objectFit: "cover", // cover inherently occludes and doesnt render the cropped portion
  transform: "translate(0,10vh)"
};
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div style={appContainerStyle} className="App">
      <div style={imageContainerStyle}>
        <img style={bgImageStyle} src={bgImage} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it's not cropping, but when you transform an element, it keeps it's props like width, height, so the `object-fit: cover` will give the same result, consider it as transforming an encapsulated box that keeps it's own behavior and style,

as a solution to achieve what you need, you can make the container works as a window for the image, without using object-fit for the image,

ex:

for the container you can add:

```
  overflow: "hidden"
```

then for the image you can have it styled like this:

```
const bgImageStyle = {
  width: "100%",
  maxWidth: "100%",
};
```

Note that: using width in this example is okay when having a portrait orientation image, you may need to replace it with `height` and `max-height` if it's a landscape orientation image